# how can i check for empty array inside request variable in laravel?

Tags: laravel, controller

**Code:**

```
public function specificationsave(Request $request) {   
    if (!empty($request->product_id)) {
        if (empty($request->specificationkeys) && empty($request->specificationvalues)) {
            return response()->json(["message" => 'Empty form submitted'], 202);
        } else {
            // something code 
        }
    } else {
        return response()->json(["message" => 'something went wrong with product'], 403);
    }
}
```

**Form code:**

```
<input type="text" name="specificationkeys[]"/>
<input type="text" name="specificationvalues[]"/>
```

**Problem:**

When I am putting empty condition on my `specificationkeys` array it is not working, because my key has a empty array so I can i check that the key has array or not or as I want empty check without validator because fields are not mandatory.

Comment: show us `dd($request->specificationkeys)` and `dd($request->specificationvalues)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example `product_id` is  return as `array` check condition like this

```
if($request->product_id && is_array($request->product_id) && count($request->product_id) > 0) {
     //success validation
}else {
    //failed validation 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use simple count function for this.

```
 if (count($request->specificationkeys) == 0 && count($request->specificationvalues) == 0){
     //your logic for empty
  }else{
    //Your logic for not empty  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function specificationsave(Request $request) {   
    if (isset($request->product_id) && !empty($request->product_id)) {
        if (is_array($request->specificationkeys) && 
            count($request->specificationkeys) !== 0 && 
            is_array($request->specificationvalues) && 
            count($request->specificationvalues) !== 0) {
            return response()->json(["message" => 'Empty form submitted'], 202);
        } else {
            // something code 
        }
    } else {
        return response()->json(["message" => 'something went wrong with product'], 403);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if file array is passed to request how can i check for images in that

Comment: [Here](https://3v4l.org/YEcBs) is example how check array with images from request @JagdishSharma